# Model save does not save all fields

Tags: magento-1.7, forms, fieldsets

```
print_r($model->getData())
```

when i am using this, it shows array like

```
array(
field1 => value1,
field2 => value2,
field3 => value3
)
```

But When I use `$model->save()` , It saves `null` to `field3` instead of `value3`.

What would be the problem.

P.S fields are all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `field3` the only column that's not saved correctly? If that's the case you might want to clear  contents of **var/cache** folder.
This could happen if `field3` is a newly added column and Zend_Db cache your db table.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works.....!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear this @Vivek!